# Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component (@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, bubble-chart

I want to create BubbleChart in my project with different colors. I saw the library `react-bubble-chart-d3.` but when i run the code it is throwing error i.e unable to find node on an unmounted component.

Code is included herewith.

--

My BubbleChart Component..

```
import React from "react";
import BubbleChart from "@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3";
import useScreenSize from "use-screen-size";

export default function BubbleChartRBC() {
  const size = useScreenSize();

  const bubbleClick = (label: any) => {
    console.log("Custom bubble click func");
  };
  const legendClick = (label: any) => {
    console.log("Customer legend click func");
  };

  return (
    <BubbleChart
      graph={{
        zoom: 1,
      }}
      width={size.width}
      height={1300}
      padding={0} // optional value, number that set the padding between bubbles
      showLegend={false} // optional value, pass false to disable the legend.
      legendPercentage={20} // number that represent the % of with that legend going to use.
      legendFont={{
        family: "Arial",
        size: 12,
        color: "#000",
        weight: "bold",
      }}
      valueFont={{
        family: "Arial",
        size: 12,
        color: "#fff",
        weight: "bold",
      }}
      labelFont={{
        family: "Arial",
        size: 16,
        color: "#fff",
        weight: "bold",
      }}
      //Custom bubble/legend click functions such as searching using the label, redirecting to other page
      bubbleClickFunc={bubbleClick}
      legendClickFun={legendClick}
      data={[
        { label: "CRM", value: 1 },
        { label: "API", value: 1 },
        { label: "Data", value: 1 },
        { label: "Commerce", value: 1 },
        { label: "AI", value: 3 },
        { label: "Management", value: 5 },
        { label: "Testing", value: 6 },
        { label: "Mobile", value: 9 },
        { label: "Conversion", value: 9 },
        { label: "Misc", value: 21 },
        { label: "Databases", value: 22 },
        { label: "DevOps", value: 22 },
        { label: "Javascript", value: 23 },
        { label: "Languages / Frameworks", value: 25 },
        { label: "Front End", value: "26" },
        { label: "Content", value: 26 },
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

I am calling it simply like..

```
return (
   <BubbleChartRBC />
);
```

After running it is showing error i.e

```
Error: Unable to find node on an unmounted component.
```

[image]

```
"react": "^18.1.0",
"@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3": "^1.0.12",
```

Do let me know if you have any solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The library is broken on React 17 and above https://github.com/weknowinc/react-bubble-chart-d3/issues/37. You probably want to consider another library with a bigger community.

Comment: Thanks @adsy Can you please recommend any other library ?

Comment: I was just looking! I know many but this particular chart type seems quite elusive. One think you could try is this PR of the lib you are using https://github.com/weknowinc/react-bubble-chart-d3/pull/36. In the package.json you can change the value for the entry to `"@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3": "lucia-gomez/react-bubble-chart-d3"` and it will download that fork from github when you next `npm install`. Im not certain, but the code change in that fork could well fix this issue.

Comment: In addition to this youd need to change your imports to `import BubbleChart from "@weknow/react-bubble-chart-d3/src"` (with src added).